How can I get line numbers that changed and added for a commit
I want to get the modified line numbers for a file in a single commit by bash script.
I searched a lot and got a script like:
git diff --unified=0 HEAD origin/develop .gitlab-ci.yml | grep -Po '^\+\+\+ ./\K.*|^@@ -[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)? \+\K[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?(?= @@)'

But this script only displays the modified line number without added lines. Does anyone know how to do that?
Example:
local .gitlab-ci.yml File:
a
b
c

remote develop branch:
a
k

The script should output 2 and 3. Because line 2 was changed and added a new line "c", the line number is 3, so it should output 2 and 3.

Preface
You first ask for modifications for a single commit while the question later asks comparing against a remote branch which can be anything from zero to unlimited number of commits.
Also you ask about changed lines, however this is impossible for any computer program to determine.
Solution
With that said, here is what I think you are asking for. If it had been just changes in a single commit you could use git blame $THE_COMMIT -- filename and then filter out only the lines with $THE_COMMIT's sha value. The blame lines contains a line number directly so the next step is just to extract that.
For comparing multiple commits then git blame does not work, however there exists a git diff-blame tool that does what the name suggest and could be used in the same way, although you want to use the downstream branch of my fork to have it not print ansi colour formatting in pipes and to support diffing individual files.
# NB, the -- before the file name is mandatory.
git diff-blame HEAD origin/develop -- .gitlab-ci.yml \
    | grep '^ [+-]' \
    | cut -d ')' -f1 \
    | rev \
    | awk '{print $1}' \
    | rev
# Assuming no ")" in the author name.


Thanks for your comment! Apologize for my unclear description. I just wanna compare a single commit, but I don't know how to use git blame to extract line numbers.

@DavidWong Just run git blame on the file and you'll see that each line has a prefix with some meta information like commit id, date, author etc, including at the very end the line number. So you can filter that out either with sed/perl/python or with cut+rev+awk line in my answer.

I found git diff command with regular expression solved my question. Thank you anyway!  The command is git diff --unified=0 --word-diff=porcelain origin/develop HEAD fileName | grep -E '^([+-]{3}|\@\@)' | grep -oP '^\+\+\+ \./\K.*|^\@\@ -[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)? \+[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?(?= \@\@)'
